# Swift Expandable Search Bar in Header?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have a table view that I would like to be able to search through. I understand how to do that, but is there a way that I can have a bar button item that expands to a search bar (of a certain width) right inside my table view header? For example, can I make something like below in swift?

[image: Expandable Search Bar]

Comment: I believe all favors should be repaid. Would you like this in the navigation bar or simply at the top of the view?

Comment: Thanks! Inside the Navigation Bar, on the right side

Comment: I had just finished a demo but it seems like it was already answered. If you need another option feel free to reply and I will post it. :)

Comment: Hey do you think I could see the one you made? @LinkOpenheim

Comment: @LinkOpenheim would you mind to show it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a working example:

[image]

```
class ExpandableView: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .green
        translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return UILayoutFittingExpandedSize
    }
}


class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var leftConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        assert(navigationController != nil, "This view controller MUST be embedded in a navigation controller.")

        // Expandable area.
        let expandableView = ExpandableView()
        navigationItem.titleView = expandableView

        // Search button.
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .search, target: self, action: #selector(toggle))

        // Search bar.
        let searchBar = UISearchBar()
        searchBar.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        expandableView.addSubview(searchBar)
        leftConstraint = searchBar.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: expandableView.leftAnchor)
        leftConstraint.isActive = false
        searchBar.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: expandableView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: expandableView.topAnchor).isActive = true
        searchBar.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: expandableView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    }

    @objc func toggle() {

        let isOpen = leftConstraint.isActive == true

        // Inactivating the left constraint closes the expandable header.
        leftConstraint.isActive = isOpen ? false : true

        // Animate change to visible.
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.alpha = isOpen ? 0 : 1
            self.navigationItem.titleView?.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to keep the navigation bar that is already there? (That has my menu button on the other side)

Comment: I'd suggest you fiddle with the `constant` of `leftConstraint` so that your menu button is never covered by the search bar. Also, change all occurrences of `greenColor` to `clearColor` to show the normal navigation bar underneath (your original navigation bar is underneath).

Comment: Thanks for the great example. I copied your example code to test it out, but am getting a weird result. It seems like the searchbar expands from the center when opened, and juts to the right upon being closed (as if the left constraint was being removed and *then* the width constraint was being activated, even though both are triggred in the same animation block. Here's a gif of what I'm getting with the above code https://media.giphy.com/media/xUOxeVUTJPfggxG0nK/giphy.gif
I tried making some adjustmnts and have gotten close, but I'd love to see if there's a better way to get the above result

Comment: @Eden I've updated the solution with re-written code, let me know if it still doesn't work for you.

Comment: @paulvs wow, great solution (why didn't I think of that?! :P) Thanks for the update!

Comment: @Eden thanks! No worries, I'm also surprised at how much simpler it really was ;-)

Comment: I'm still having a bit of trouble trying to constrain that right edge. I tried anchors and adding right side constraints to the expandableview/titleview, but neither seemed to work. https://media.giphy.com/media/3ohs82btXvJMP48qTC/giphy.gif I really want that expandableview's right edge to stick to the rightbarbutton's left edge, but something is making it think it's allowed to encroach on the rightbarbutton

Comment: is there a reason why `expandableView.superview!.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: expandableView, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: expandableView.superview!, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 60))` or `expandableView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor, constant: 60).isActive = true` shouldn't do the job?

Comment: Are you overriding `intrinsicContentSize` and returning `UILayoutFittingExpandedSize` as shown above?

Comment: From the gif I can see that the search bar is positioned correctly when it's shown, and when it's animating to hidden its right edge is not sticking to the left edge of the search bar button, like you said. Are you sure you're not modifying the search bar's right constraint in any way when hiding it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159270/discussion-between-eden-and-paulvs).